# XML fetching and parsing solution/library that works with Ruby 1.9.1 on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, parsing

Does anyone know of a library that works with Ruby 1.9.1 on Rails 3 yet?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri (parsing) and Typhoeus (fetching) are compatible. Also, I've just updated Feedzirra to be Rails 3 compatible. Version 0.0.22.

[nokigiri](http://nokogiri.org/)
[typhoeus](http://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus)
[feedzirra](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra/)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will try these out. I logged the issue in Feedzirra's github issue tracker. As I said in my message on github, let me know if there is anything I can do to help get Feedzirra working with Ruby 1.9. Best, Nick

Answer (score 0):

The problem shouldn't be from rails as it's a generic library, which can work with rails or without it.
However if you look at the readme, in the section "next steps", you'll see :

> Test against Ruby 1.9.1 and fix any bugs.

The library hasn't been tester with Ruby 1.9.1. So the problem should come from there.
If it's not compatible with Ruby 1.9.1, you only have two solutions :

- Track the errors and fix them (if possible without breaking the library on 1.8).
- Find an other library compatible with 1.9.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the question to try and get a more general response. I do like the Feedzirra library and will continue to support it but I would like to know if there are any other similar solutions. Thanks again.